# Tell ifort to show tool commands

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

Say I have two files file_1.f90 and file_2.f90 and they use some libraries. Could be any programming language. Then I compile and link in one step using

```
ifort -I/include_dir_loc -o my.o file_1.f90 file_2.f90 -L/Lib_dir_loc
```

Is there a way to tell the terminal or ifort or whoever takes over to tell me the individual steps it carries out. It could be that it goes

```
ifort -I/include_dir_loc  -c -o file_1.f90
ifort -I/include_dir_loc  -c -o file_2.f90
ifort -o my.o file_1.o file_2.o -L/Lib_dir_loc
```

What actually happens after I type the first command? Who carries out the compilation using what commands and who coordinates between the compiler and the linker?

Answer (score 4):

for ifort:

`-v` will show the tool commands and execute them

`-dryrun` will show the tool commands but will not execute